# Cannot send a tweet message. Error has occurred in ios5

Tags: iphone, ios

Hi I am using ios5 twitter integration, I know that one unique message will not post 2nd time on twitter.

But trying to send same message 2nd time, it is showing alert message as "Can Not Send tweet".

It is good. but immediately, it goes to

```
if(result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone) 
{

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" message:@"tweet posted successfully" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

And showing this message. I think it is a bug, please tell me how to rectify this issue.

Comment: Is this your code or Tweeter ios implementation ?

Comment: this is twitter ios5 implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 5 twitter integration,

`TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult` just has 2 options

When user selects done -- `TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone`

When user selects cancel -- `TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancel`

This result doesn't depend on the tweets updated by apple in background. If the tweets fail while updating it shows an alert.

SO i suggest do not implement any custom pop-up for success or failure.
As apple itself implemented indications for success/failure tweet updates. On success it plays a sound & on failure a pop-up with reason.